# SecItemAdd returning status 0 while leaving persistent_ref empty

Tags: ios, certificate, identity, keychain, client-certificates

When trying to save an identity to my keychain, I use the following code. It only works sometimes, but the majority of the times, no persistent reference is returned.

I use the following apple provided function:

```
CFDataRef persistentRefForIdentity(SecIdentityRef identity)
{
    CFTypeRef persistent_ref = NULL;

    const void *keys[] = { kSecReturnPersistentRef, kSecValueRef };
    const void *values[] = { kCFBooleanTrue, identity };

    CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 2, NULL, NULL);

    OSStatus s = SecItemAdd(dict, &persistent_ref);

    if (dict)
        CFRelease(dict);

    return (CFDataRef)persistent_ref;
}
```

The code returned by SecItemAdd is 0, yet `persistent_ref` stays NULL, or 0x0. The weirdest part of this all is that it sometimes does save the identity. What's going on?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the exact same problem myself...

Comment: I believe it turned out this code was working, and my bug was elsewhere. It had to do with the ssl cache of nsurlsession that was not refreshing. If you'd like i can post my 'working' snippet of this code, however, i dont think i changed it.